# How to integrate stripe into chrome extension with manifest V3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, stripe-payments, manifest, strip

**Following are the error while working:**

1. Not working with sr in script tag like following:

   `<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/" async></script>`
2. After adding it manually now mounting card but not know how to create checkout after form submission with card values.
3. Following function not working:

   ```
   fetch('/create-checkout-session', {
     method: 'POST',
   })
   .then(function (response) {
     console.log('response', response);
     // return response.json();
   })
   .then(function (session) {
     console.log('session', session);
     // return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
   })
   .then(function (result) {
     console.log('result', result)
     // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
     // error, you should display the localized error message to your
     // customer using `error.message`.
     // if (result.error) {
     //   alert(result.error.message);
     // }
   });
   ```

**error:**

```
POST chrome-extension://nldmbdiekelgaahflcjkhigmiochfaib/create-checkout-session net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```